Starting nginx on ubuntu return unknown error
When I start NGINX on Ubuntu, it return the error like this. I have changed the server port but it didn't work.
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)


Check for existing processes: Make sure there are no other processes already listening on port 80. You can use the following command to check:
sudo netstat -tuln | grep :80


I killed all processes listening on port 80. However, i can just run "nginx" once, the next times it return the same error.

emmm..., if you want to restart nginx  , please use sudo nginx -s reload  and stop command is sudo nginx -s stop
